# Axi2 Web Service - HTTP 500

Tags: java, android, eclipse, service, apache-axis

**I have written an Axis Web Service in Eclipse.**

After i deployed the war file on the server i tried to connect in an android application.

There i get an HTTP 500 ERROR.

I have no idea about the Http 500 error with this error message:

```
    [ERROR] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '3' (code 51) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,323]
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '3' (code 51) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,323]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:709)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMElementImpl.java:724)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getChildren(OMElementImpl.java:373)
        at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:602)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processRequest(RPCUtil.java:153)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:206)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1509)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '3' (code 51) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,323]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:648)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2854)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1019)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:668)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 26 more
```

I don't know where i could start to find the file where the error is in it.

Is the wsdl file wrong ?

Please let me know if you need my wsdl file for finding a solution.

Thanks for you help.

Best Regards

Comment: The error says it all. Whatever your service is spitting out, it's not what is expected by the receiver.

Comment: What you could do to debug it, is to use Wireshark (or tcpdump) to capture the traffic and see what XML document is sent. The exception printed suggests, that some XML element in that document is <3...> (starts with '3'), which is not a valid XML (valid XML tags cannot start with a digit).

Comment: Ok thanks for you help. You mean the XML from server to client or the request from client to server?

I don't know where i should start to search